# Ubuntu not connecting to switch box

Tags: 12.04, server

I recently took my dad's old computer to use at a multimedia server, but when i hooked it up to the Ethernet switch (the computer sits under my desk so my main computer shares the switch) and it says its connected but i cant even access my router page. My main computer connects fine, but the Ubuntu computer doesn't...

Answer (score 0):

You must configure network. Maybe you can put network card to grab ip via dhcp if you router is configured on that way.

On this links you can see manual and configuration using a network manager

http://www.sitepoint.com/ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-networking-tips-and-tricks/

and

http://www.php2s.com/linux/how-to-configure-network-using-cli-ang-gui-in-ubuntu-12-04.html